# How to disable android navigation bar when soft keyboard is enabled?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

[image]

when an android soft keyboard is enabled via the interaction with an input field, the navigation bar is also enabled along with the keyboard. Is there any way to disable/hide the navigation bar in this case?

This is implemented in Unity#d, but if a solution is available in android, it can be added as plug-in to unity as well. Any direction or solution is helpful, thanks.

app supported API version is from 22 to 32.

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution to it as setting fullscreen window with render outside safe area mark doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

If you want a easier option You could just set the Fullscreen mode to `Fullscreen Window`[image: Fullscreen Window]

`Android Player settings -> Resolution and Presentation`

As the Documentation reads

> In this mode the **navigation bar is always hidden**. This replaces the Start in fullscreen mode option.

still I'd suggest having a look at [Unity tidbits](http://with%20an%20input%20field,%20the%20navigation%20bar%20is%20also%20enabled%20along%20with%20the%20keyboard.%20Is)

When implementing it in your Unity project, you can hide or show the `Navigation Bar` or `Status Bar` via code. so you could just check `OnPointerClick` and when it happens set

```cs
ImmersiveAndroid.navigationBarState = ImmersiveAndroid.States.Hidden;
```

Comment: The full-screen window is already enabled, I tried Unity tidbits, it didn't work. Have you tried and it is working for you?

Comment: yes it did work in my project. The navigation bar hide works on android 4.4 (Kitkat ) and above only. If its below android 4.4, it works but just without hiding navigation bar.(Since this feature is given by android only after Kitkat - 4.4) are you sure you meet the requirments?

Comment: Also the Navigation bar coming up whilst keyboard is present is a android feature and that doesn't stop during ImmersiveMode so I'd say your best bet would be to edit the  ``AndroidManifest.xml`` and just add ``activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>`` but adjustPan is generally not the right solution if you are using ``ScollViews`` or ``action bars``.

Comment: I tried the adjustPan as well. It didn't work. Navigation bar is enabled along with keyboard. Can you provide me the example project that you test on. I can check it for the any missing changes.

Comment: Setting Fullscreen window and also setting Render outside safe area doesnt works